# How to prove the linear transformation is surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a nonzero vector space over a field $F$, and suppose that $S$ is a basis for $V$. Let $\mathcal{C}(S,F)$ denote the vector space of all functions $f\in \mathcal{F}(S,F)$ such that $f(s)=0$ for all but a finite number of vectors in $S$. Let $\Psi:\mathcal{C}(S,F)\to V$ be the function defined by
> $$\Psi(f)=\sum_{s\in S,\ f(s)\neq0}f(s)s.$$
> Prove that $\Psi$ is an isomorphism. Thus every nonzero vector space can be viewed as a space of functions.

Assume $S$ is {$s_1,s_2 .... s_n$}.

Give a $v$ in $V$ , $v$=$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\times s_i$ , and $a_i$ are all nonzero.

How can we find a function $f$ in $C(S,F)$ such that $\psi$(f) = $v$ if there only has finite number of $f(s_i)$ nonzero?

Comment: Define $f(s_i)=a_i$ and check that this $f$ satisfies all requirements.

Comment: You're assuming that $S$ is finite, which is not true in general.

Comment: My fault, but the exercise doesn't say it can't be a limited size of S, either. 
Can I assume it can be proven with S being infinite or finite?

Comment: Yes, the exercise is right in not assuming anything about $S$. Let $v\in V$ i.e. $v=\sum_{s\in T}a_ss$ for some finite $T\subset S.$ Then $v=\psi(f)\iff f(s)=a_s$ for every $s\in T$ and $f(s)=0$ for every $s\in S\setminus T.$ So, there exists a unique $f$ s.t. $\psi(f)=v$. This proves that $\psi$ is bijective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $S=\{s_\lambda|\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ is a basis of $V$, where $\Lambda$ is an indexing set.

Now, consider an arbitrary $w\in V$ such that $$w=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda^\prime}\alpha_\lambda s_\lambda,$$ where $\Lambda^\prime$ is some finite subset of $\Lambda$ and $\alpha_\lambda\in F$. Choose $g\in\mathcal{F}(S,F)$ such that
$$g(s_\lambda)=\begin{cases}
\alpha_\lambda, \ \text{if} \ \lambda\in\Lambda^\prime\\
0, \ \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}.$$
Then $g\in\mathcal{C}(S,F)$ and
$$\Psi(g)=\sum_{s\in S, \ g(s)\neq0}g(s)s=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda^\prime}\alpha_\lambda s_\lambda=w.$$
Therefore, $\Psi$ is surjective.

Comment: Why  arbitrary $w ∈ V$ uses a finite subset $Λ'$ of $Λ$ , instead of $Λ$ itself?
What if  a $w$ happens to be formed by  #$(Λ')+1$ ~ #$(Λ)$  elements in $S$?

Comment: @thentust your confusion arises from the definition of "span" in infinite dimensional vector spaces, the definition is that a vector $v$ is in the span of some set $S$ if if can be written as a finite linear combination of members from $S$. You might be wondering why "infinite" linear combinations aren't allowed, and the reason is quite simply because they can't be satisfactorily defined in an arbitrary vector space, one needs at least a norm to interpret the notion of convergence of an infinite sum

Comment: @thentust Carlyle have already provided a really nice answer for your question. You can find more information about bases for infinite dimensional vector spaces here: https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/infinite.pdf

Comment: Thanks, it is reasonable for infinite dimensional spaces, even though the concept of infinite is much more abstract to me.
Then in this question, can we take $V$ as a finite dimensional space($S$ is finite) as well ?

Comment: @thentust The problem given in your post is from the book Linear Algebra, by Friedberg et al. In the fourth edition, at page 44, they have written "In this book, we are primarily interested in vector spaces having finite
bases". Thus, perhaps it is not a bad idea to assume that $V$ is a finite dimensional space. In this case, if $\dim V=n$, then you can modify my answer choosing $\Lambda=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $\Lambda^\prime=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Consequently, $$w=\sum_{\lambda=1}^n\alpha_\lambda s_\lambda.$$

Comment: @thentust However, the finiteness of $S$ is an assumption not supported by anything in the statement of the problem.

Comment: @QuantumSuperfield
Okay, One more question perhaps: 
"$C(S,F)$ denote the vector space of all functions $f∈F(S,F)$ such that $f(s)=0$
 for all but a finite number of vectors in $S$."
Does $C(S,F)$ also contain functions which put every element in S into nonzero element in F if S is finite?

Comment: @thentust Yes, you are right if $S$ is finite.

Comment: @QuantumSuperfield
Is this may be one of the reason $ψ$ is surjective if $S$ is finite?
If $C(F,S)$ DIDN'T contain the f such that f(s) = nonzero element in $F$ for all $s$ in $S$, then we can't find an f in $C(F,S)$ to satisfy surjective property,
because every $ψ$(f) may have some missing vectors to form a $w$ in $V$?

p.s. You may find my grammar weired because I'm not english-native speaker,  so please bear with my poor elaboration. Thanks.